# Make a whole Xcode project a library for external integration

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a whole project developed under iOS which is a sales channel / ecommerce app which is a white branded product.

It mainly relies on a webapp but the native container handles a lot of features (session management, additional services, register to push notification) which is not only intented to make distribution on AppStore possible.
Thus, lot of code within the application delegate, use of several libraries through CocoaPods, etc.

Now, some of our customers whould love to integrate this ecommerce in their existing native apps, for instance, as a tab in a UITabBarController.

What is the best approach to do so ? Considering notably that both AppDelegate must be called, etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would advice to refactor your code and extract as much as possible to add it into your own Framework if you really want to keep it clean and have a good way of providing support to your customers. (refactor in a way so that it is easy to use for external projects, for example providing delegates/blocks in a matter that is straight-forward to implement).

A great starting point for learning how to create (Objective-C) iOS Frameworks can be found at https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework.

Any dependency (external library) you use for building the Framework will become a dependency for the project that will use your framework, unless you can add the source in your Framework.

Also take a look into providing documentation using Doxygen, AppleDoc, etc ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. My main issue remains on CocoaPods, as I am using .Xcworkspace instead of .xcproject for the project to work, it's really a mess to incorporate the dependencies to another existing project.